# extract symmetric Key from p12 private key

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I am trying to decrypt the data for that 
I have private key stored in a .p12 file and with that, I have to extract the symmetric key from the private key but I am not getting any solution how to do it.
It will be great if I get some help on this

Comment: your question make no sense at all. There is no symmetric key in a .p12 file.

Comment: @JamesKPolk It can contain symmetric keys actually, it's not as common though. Java 9 is able to use the PKCS#12 key store with symmetric keys. But you cannot extract a secret key from a private key - it's not a usual operation anyway. You can decrypt some wrapped key though, which is called unwrapping.